# How to expire a file not the directory in S3 bucket using lifecycle policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose I got two directories (objects) in an S3 bucket:

> /dir1/test.csv
>
> /dir2/logs.txt

I want .csv files to be expired after 15 days but not the directory so that ideally after 15 days I should have only two empty directories in the bucket:

> /dir1/
>
> /dir2/

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, AWS does not offer anything like a real directory in S3; it's only the key name.

It means when you save file "/dir2/logs.txt" to S3, your key name is "/dir2/logs.txt", that's all.

So, when you delete the files use that keys, all of them disappear.

For more information read the following doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html